# How to track (outlinking) direct advertisements on site

Tags: javascript, html, url, ads, referrals

I have a site I'm selling direct ads to businesses for, and was wondering how to track and measure how much traffic I am sending their way? This way we will both know how the agreement is playing out.  Is there a free service or code snippet for this? I know he can track it in google analytics by referrals, but I would like to know this info as well.

Comment: Please try showing us what have you done so far to achieve this like what materials you've read about this? did you do any initial coding first? What is your expected outcome in code etc.. Read more about [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Inuka - I am in the midst of researching this, just looking for a solution whether that means a link to a service or custom code snippet, etc. that allows me to track how much traffic my site is sending to the advertiser.